# Execute sequence of queries from a text file - OrientDB Console

Tags: orientdb

I want to execute queries which are stored in text file on OrientDB console.

I am currently referring to https://github.com/sslavic/orientdb-wiki/blob/master/Console-Commands.md Batch Mode, but getting unrecognized command error.

Comment: Could you provide more info about what you've tried? What exactly yields that error?

Answer (score 2):

from the terminal you must go in the folder "bin" of your version of OrientDb
and you must give the command console.bat path of your file.txt

Comment: Thank you! **Why is this so?** It also seems to work when you provide the full absolute path to the `file.txt` (e.g. `/home/user/file.txt`) (you don't have to be inside the `bin` folder)

Answer (score 1):

I've tryed with the last snapshot and i've no problem with this console command.
In your file.txt make sure you dont miss any semicolon, probably you have some parsing problem in your file or any othter sintaxt/typo issue, so orient can not find a suitable command for some string, dont know if you can post your code.. but at least update with the full console output.

Comment: I get `!Unrecognized command: 'commands.txt'`, so it's not something _inside_ the file, but the console incorrectly recognizes the filename as a command.
It works when I change the working directory to `bin` (where the `console.sh` is) or when I provide the full absolute path to the file